# Symfony2 custom user checker based on accepted eula

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm, eula

I want to create custom user checker to validate login action against last accepted eula.
'
Idea is quite simple, there will be many versions of eula and user **can't** login untill he accept the lastest eula.

Scenario is:

1. User creates new account and accepts eula.
2. Eula gets updated
3. User tries to login, but he didnt accept lastest eula
4. User gets the same login form but with additional field "accept newest eula"
5. User logs in and system inserts information: Current date and time, User id, Eula id to keep track of eula acceptance.

I found this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2/D0V0bFks9S0/Qg9mrbpfB3IJ

But unfortunately there is no full version of custom user checker. How do I implement the rest of it?

Comment: I know this question is dated... But I'm facing a situation where I feel the need to override the user checker. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 8):

The answer is actually quite obvious.
In your custom bundle:

config.yml

```
parameters:
    security.user_checker.class: Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Security\UserChecker
```

Userchecker:

```
class UserChecker extends BaseUserChecker
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        //do your custom preauth stuff here
        parent::checkPreAuth($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine Symfony's user checker service (`security.user_checker`) in your bundle:

```
# services.yml
security.user_checker:
    class: MyBundle\Checker\UserChecker
    arguments: [ "@some.service", "%some.param%" ]
```

Then extend Symfony's UserChecker:

```
# UserChecker.php

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker as BaseUserChecker;

class UserChecker extends BaseUserChecker
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        parent::checkPreAuth($user);

        // your stuff
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        parent::checkPostAuth($user);

        // your stuff
    }
}
```

The `security.user_checker` service gets called in `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider::authenticate()` during the authentication process

Comment: in your services.yml please change to: `services:
  security.user_checker:`

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach event listener to the `kernel.request` event and watch if the current logged user has accepted the latest EULA?

To get the current user you can use something like this:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
if (!$securityContext) {
    return;
}

$user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
```

Comment: Event listener would be the same as checking on every user action. Maybe more flexible but still you would be authenticated in this case. I need to check this **before** user would be authed.

Comment: In this case you should use a marked stored inside the session. You can get the session from the request, which is available in this event.