# Symfony: Hooking into login process to check for additional conditions

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I implemented the advanced user interface of Symfony in my project. It works to register and login users.

Now I have additional conditions I want to check when the user logs in. Like if the user has confirmed his or her email already and/or other conditions. Those conditions are fields in the database/properties of the user entity so it's easy to check them.

Imagine I want to add a `isEmailConfirmed()` function to the user class which is called like the `isEnabled()` function from the advanced user interface. If it returns true the user is able to login. If it returns false I want to restrict access and show a message that addresses the problem.

--> Is it correct, to add such a function to the `checkPreAuth()` function in `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker`? I am thinking of hooking in here with a function like `checkCustomConditions()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the authentication process, when trying to authenticate a user, first the provider takes the credentials and retrieves the user from the storage (db, active directory). Then the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker::preAuth()` method is called before actually creating a token for the user. Here exceptions are thrown specifically for each of the cases you mention above. You can catch them in your loginAction and interpret them.

I guess the least intrusive way to add your own preAuth logic would be to try an overwrite the definition of the provider (if you are using a default one) to use your own UserChecker.

Comment: This helped a lot: When searching for the methods directly I found a post on SO that describes how to overwrite the service user_checker and how to implement my own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100628/symfony2-custom-user-checker-based-on-accepted-eula